# ng build --prod gives no such file or directory error for the specified outDir in angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My angular project fails to build when I try to build for prod (**ng build --prod**). Please note **ng build** seems to work fine.

I get the below error when I try to build with --prod option

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\dev\workspaces\intellij-workspaces\myproject\web\target\frontend'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:922:18)
```

I have set my angular-cli outDir as below

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "web"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../../../target/frontend",
      "deployUrl": "myproject-dashboard/",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
```

My package.json and angular-cli.json files are present under
myproject/web/src/main/frontend

So, ideally based on the relative path set for outDir in angular-cli.json, I would expect a folder called target to be created under **myproject/web** folder and all my build output to be available there.

Please can you let me know if I should be creating the target folder manually or it there a way to tell angular-cli to create it automatically?

Comment: if you set `"outDir": "dist"` does that work for you this way? Do you have a permissions to write to `../../../target/frontend` ?   What is your `ng -v` ?
I just set `"outDir": "../../target/frontend"` and have no issues to run `ng build --prod`  using cli `1.3.2` and node `7.8`

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that you have some other problem in your code, which gots hidden by subsequent exception from the webpack, as described in this ticket:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7203

What's going on there? Build fails on compilation and thus does not create your output directory, but then CLI still performs other steps, one of which (the extraction of library licenses by webpack) requires that output directory shall exist. That step fails and get logged instead of the root cause.

Try adding `--no-extract-licenses` option to your `ng build -prod` command. This worked for me with exactly the same error as in your case.

Comment: `--no-extract-licenses` saved me, thanks! However, I was not able to pinpoint the issue causing the build fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, what I did to resolve that is add this in my package.json file :

```
"scripts": {
  // ...
  "build": " mkdir dist && ng build --prod"
},
```

(given that your dest folder is dist)

Comment: Then you run it with npm run build

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That doesn't completely help as I might want run ng build --prod directly and also I develop locally from windows and deploy the production instance to a unix box. So mkdir will fail as incorrect syntax in windows.

Comment: Ok, I wrongly thought that you were using Linux in production, my bad. What you still could try is `ng build --output-path=dist --prod` (given your folder is dist)

Comment: And I guess it doesn't work ... My solution was the mkdir, I can't really help you beyond that, my last guess is to update @angular/cli to the latest version ?

Comment: i tried what you suggested. . But got the same error as follows                            
> web@0.0.0 build C:\dev\workspaces\intellij-workspaces\myproject\web\src\main\frontend
> ng build --output-path=../../../target/frontend --prod

fs.js:922
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\dev\workspaces\intellij-workspaces\myproject\web\target\frontend'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:922:18)
    at licensePlugin.write (C:\dev\workspaces\intellij-

Comment: I hate that stackoverflow does not let you format your response in the comment section, sorry for giving the output so cluttered in the above comment. But yes, it did not work starting from command line as admin. Thanks a lot for your help. Will wait my luck to see if someone has seen this issue better.

Comment: No problem, I still can read it. Did you also try to update @angular/cli to its latest version ?

Answer (score -1):

i got the same error - i was trying to run the command from the dist folder...  when i changed back to the root folder of the project, and then it worked fine